# Set child of flex element to be height of parent?

Tags: css, flexbox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8om6dxt6/)

I wish to have `a` to the left and `b` to the right. In the center is a list aligned horizontally. I want the `full-height` div to be the height of the parent.

So:

```
a            1 2 3             b
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="full-height">
      <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
      b
  </div>
</div>
```

I've looked at other SO posts which have 2 solutions:

- Add `flex-direction: column;` to the parent. Which won't work in this situation as parent needs to be horizontally laid out.
- Set parent height and make child `height: 100%`. I need the parents height to be dynamic.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8om6dxt6/1/ Did you just try removing the .a css selector from your styles? That seemed to have worked.

Comment: Sean Kwon - why? That .a selector is to make the a div's height large to illustrate the point.

Comment: Well, when you set the height of the .a container, that doesn't neccessarily center the text as well. I mean, it dynamically resizes the container but the text doesn't follow. What you want is `line-height: 300px` https://jsfiddle.net/8om6dxt6/2/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/8om6dxt6/3/?

Comment: Sean Kwon - nope, .full-height should be 100% height of the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `align-self:stretch;` on the `.full-height` element.

To align elements inside the list I added:

```
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
```

to the `.full-height` and  `a`, also removed the padding from the ul.

### UPDATE 1:

Updated to meet the comment. Moved flex content to `ul` instead of `.full-height` and added height 100% to `ul`.

You can read more about how flex works in [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35#.bzk34hue0).

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  background: gold;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.a{
  height: 300px;
     align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.full-height{
  background: tomato;
  align-self: stretch;
}

ul{
  height:100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    a
  </div>
   <div class="full-height">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div>
    b
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how I can make a div inside of .full-height 100% height of it's parent too?

Comment: @panthro You mean the `ul`? if so - you can add `height:100%;` to it and it will be full height.

Comment: And then vertically align its contents?

Comment: @panthro Updated answer